# How often do we use m-ary decision trees?

Tags: decision-trees

If I come across decision trees, it is a binary tree with predicates internal nodes.
How often do we use m-ary decision trees?
Is there any combination of m-ary and binary decision tree, e.g. first level of the tree is binary and second level of the tree consists of m-ary?
Same question arises for Random Forest.

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/51983/55122
and https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12187/232706

Comment: @BenReiniger Thank you for the information. It turned out that using binary tree is optimal in many aspects